# How do i add Meta Tags on panels page?

Tags: 6, panels, meta-tags

I want to generate meta tags on panels node pages. I am adding Meta tags using [nodewords module](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodewords), it works fine on other node pages except panels generated layout.

Any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

There are set of other modules which helps you create meta tags

- [Page Title](https://www.drupal.org/project/page_title)
- [Meta Tag](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag)
- [Meta Tags Quick](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatags_quick)

*Note:* Meta Tag Module supports panels too!!!

Comment: My Site is in D6 so above mentioned module will not helpful, also i can only use "Nodewords" module as i have some custom Meta Tags implemented.